# Bootstrapping Laravel environment

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I'm building a cron-like feature into my Laravel application. To ensure only 1 instance is running across multiple startup requests, I'm making the cron call to a Shell script which finally executes a PHP file.

In this PHP file in need of course access to Laravel's built-in functions and Facades. Currently I'm requiring the `public/index.php` file to bootstrap the Laravel environment. Everything is working fine, I'm able to call interact with the Laravel environment. However, it's also producing an error on each startup:

```
local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in 
/PATH_TO_LARAVEL/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:140
```

How can I prevent this error from being thrown? Or is there another way to bootstrap into Laravel?
I've also tried to require the `bootstrap/autoload.php`and `bootstrap/start.php` files separately but then the environment doesn't seem to be bootstrapped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that you need to require both the `./bootstrap/autoload.php` and `./bootstrap/start.php` scripts for the Laravel environment to start up.

Try making a file: `./bootstrap/cronloader.php`:

```
<?php
// Laravel Autoloader
require __DIR__.'/autoload.php';

// Start Laravel
require_once __DIR__.'/start.php';
```

Then simply `require_once` this at the start of your script.

Alternatively, write an [artisan command](http://laravel.com/docs/commands) to replace your script? Since you can call artisan directly from cron, and it will give you the full laravel environment.

Comment: Back in the time I indeed ended up writing an artisan command as suggested.